# Stack Exchange App - Wrong code highlighting

Tags: discussion, bug

I'm using the [Stack Exchange App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=de) on my Android device and I have wondered for quite some time why the code highlighting goes wrong there (click for large image):

[image: small version]

As you can see the `'` char is taken to start a string which is not the syntax of *Mathematica*.

Question: Is the highlighting in the app related to what happens on our page and can this be fixed? Note that I don't get any code coloring when browsing mathematica.stackexchange.com on my mobile device with Chrome.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if they disabled our huge linter file to conserve memory and improve load times on mobile.

Comment: @rm-rf Yes, that is surely possible. I guess they use the standard google-prettyprint installation.